# BeautifulSoup: get css classes from html

Tags: python, html, css, beautifulsoup

Is there a way to get CSS classes from an HTML file using `BeautifulSoup`? Example snippet:

```
<style type="text/css">

 p.c3 {text-align: justify}

 p.c2 {text-align: left}

 p.c1 {text-align: center}

</style>
```

Perfect output would be:

```
cssdict = {
    'p.c3': {'text-align': 'justify'},
    'p.c2': {'text-align': 'left'},
    'p.c1': {'text-align': 'center'}
}
```

although something like this would do:

```
L = [
    ('p.c3', {'text-align': 'justify'}),  
    ('p.c2', {'text-align': 'left'}),    
    ('p.c1', {'text-align': 'center'})
]
```

Comment: What do you expect to get? The literal text `"\n\n p.c3 {text-align: justify}\n\n..."`? Please be explicit!

Comment: By "Get CSS classes" Do you mean "Get a list of HTML classes that are used in selectors in the stylesheet"? i.e. the result you want is `['c3', 'c2', 'c1']`?

Comment: @Martin Pieters,@Quentin -- Updated the question.

Comment: So you want rulesets, not classes? You'll need to find a CSS parser. I don't think BeautifulSoup has any features along those lines (it can get the stylesheet, but not parse it).

Comment: @Quentin -- Rulesets yes, my question was wrongly put. Sorry for that. I am not sure if this(comments) is the right place to ask, but is there a reccomended css parser for doing that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

BeautifulSoup itself doesn't parse CSS style declarations at all, but you *can* extract such sections then parse them with a dedicated CSS parser.

Depending on your needs, there are several CSS parsers available for python; I'd pick [cssutils](http://cthedot.de/cssutils/) (requires python 2.5 or up (including python 3)), it is the most complete in it's support, and supports inline styles too.

Other options are [css-py](https://code.google.com/p/css-py/) and [tinycss](http://packages.python.org/tinycss/).

To grab and parse such all style sections (example with cssutils):

```
import cssutils
sheets = []
for styletag in tree.findAll('style', type='text/css')
    if not styletag.string: # probably an external sheet
        continue
    sheets.append(cssutils.parseStyle(styletag.string))
```

With `cssutil` you can then combine these, resolve imports, and even have it fetch external stylesheets.

Answer (score 7):

A BeautifulSoup & cssutils combo will do the trick nicely:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BSoup
    import cssutils
    selectors = {}
    with open(htmlfile) as webpage:
        html = webpage.read()
        soup = BSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    for styles in soup.select('style'):
        css = cssutils.parseString(styles.encode_contents())
        for rule in css:
            if rule.type == rule.STYLE_RULE:
                style = rule.selectorText
                selectors[style] = {}
                for item in rule.style:
                    propertyname = item.name
                    value = item.value
                    selectors[style][propertyname] = value
```

BeautifulSoup parses all "style" tags in the html (head & body), .encode_contents() converts the BeautifulSoup objects into a byte format that cssutils can read, and then cssutils parses the individual CSS styles all the way down to the property/value level via rule.selectorText & rule.style.

**Note:** The "rule.STYLE_RULE" filters out only styles. The [cssutils documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/index.html) details options for filtering media rules, comments and imports.

It'd be cleaner if you broke this down into functions, but you get the gist...

Comment: `soup.select('style')` only detects style declared on the page, and doesn't detect css styles declared in external CSS files

Answer (score 0):

tinycss parser exists for explicitly parsing CSS in python. BeautifulSoup supports HTML tags and specific css classes cannot be searched unless you use regular expression. This even supports some amount of CSS3.

http://packages.python.org/tinycss/

**PS:** However, it works only from python 2.6 onwards.