# CSS parsing Python for finding font-family

Tags: python, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

given a stylesheet file. I want to find out the font-family values used all over the stylesheet. Please can someone hint me on an idea to do this?

I crawled, parsed the stylesheet link using `Beautifulsoup`. But now im left with a big string of stylesheet.

Sorry if this is a noob question. Just willing to learn.

Comment: My answer there applies here too; use a CSS parser, then query it's result for the `font-family` rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [cssutils](http://pythonhosted.org/cssutils/) package, e.g.:

```
import cssutils


data = """
p{font-family:"Verdana"}

p{font-family:"Comic Sans"}

p{font-family:"Times New Roman", Times, serif}
"""

sheet = cssutils.parseString(data)

for rule in sheet:
    if rule.type == rule.STYLE_RULE:
        # find property
        for property in rule.style:
            if property.name == 'font-family':
                print property.value
```

This prints:

```
"Verdana"
"Comic Sans"
"Times New Roman", Times, serif
```

Also, see Martijn's answer here: [BeautifulSoup: get css classes from html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501268/beautifulsoup-get-css-classes-from-html).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for considering to help me. alecxe and Martijn.