# Scraping css properties of non-inline styled html elements using BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to scrape the background css property of the table cells below? I know BeautifulSoup only parses html. Is there any way to scrape the css properties of html elements if the css is not inlined?

html

```
...

<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class='cell-style'>Tuesday</td>
    <td class='cell-style'>Wednesday</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>

...
```

external css

```
.cell-style{
  background: url('/example.com')
}
```

Comment: Try [`window.getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

Comment: What language are you after?

Comment: @user1432181 Python, sorry forgot to include that.

Comment: @Tamdim were you able to solve this?  I was asking myself the same question

Comment: @abu No, unfortunately. It was for a small side project which I ended up abandoning.