# Can I get the css value of the before tag when python crawling?

Tags: python, web-crawler

[image]

i need background-image url

```
soup.select('div','css-1swthbg:before'): # not work
```

Comment: Can you post the CSS as code instead of the image?

Comment: Check this answer, you might need more than beautiful soup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501268/beautifulsoup-get-css-classes-from-html